# Why my htacess rewrite return 404?

Tags: redirect, 404-error

Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^abc/products-(.+)$ def/products-$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have many url links in /abc/ sub-directory, like

```
http://www.domain.com/abc/products-12345
http://www.domain.com/abc/products-23456
http://www.domain.com/abc/products-34567
http://www.domain.com/abc/new-items
```

Now I want to url rewrite /abc/products- to /def/products-

```
http://www.domain.com/def/products-12345
http://www.domain.com/def/products-23456
http://www.domain.com/def/products-34567
http://www.domain.com/abc/new-items
```

the code: `RewriteRule ^abc/products-(.+)$ def/products-$1 [R=301,L]` could make the page redirect, but the it when type `http://www.domain.com/abc/products-12345` the browser will go to  `http://www.domain.com/def/products-12345` but the page show as `404`. If I remove it, `http://www.domain.com/abc/products-12345` could run well. Why and How to? Thanks.

**Update:**

I have moved `RewriteRule ^abc/products-(.+)$ def/products-$1 [R=301,L]` ahead of `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` still get `404`. 
And I add `echo get_query_var('page_id');` in `404.php`, this return `0`.

why the url could redirect but miss the right page?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the stuff in "def/products" is not handled by WordPress.

Try reversing the index.php and abc/products rules, like so:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^abc/products-(.+)$ def/products-$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess is read and executed line by line. It may help to have your rule execute before WordPress's. That is the way I usually handle it.

I say 'try' because I can usually get these to work but sometimes not the first time. :)